# Задача: "Интересные числа"

Tags: python, c++

Софья считает число интересным, если его цифры идут в неубывающем порядке. Например, числа 123, 1111 или 888999 — интересные.

Софья заинтересовалась, сколько существует интересных положительных чисел, лежащих в диапазоне от L до R включительно. Это число может оказаться довольно большим для больших L и R, поэтому Софья хочет найти остаток от деления этого числа на 10^9+7.

Требуется написать программу, которая по заданным L и R определяет количество интересных чисел, лежащих в диапазоне от L до R включительно, и выводит остаток от деления этого числа на 10^9+7.

Ограничения: 1 <= L <= R <= 10^100

Пример:
Ввод: 1\n100 Вывод: 54

Я написал такой код на python:

```py
def f(n):
    res, min_num = 0, 0
    for i, j in enumerate(n):
        j = int(j)
        if j < min_num: 
            return res
        elif j > min_num:
            res += sum(a[len(n) - i][9 - x] for x in range(min_num, j))
            min_num = j
    return res + 1
L = input()
R = input()
p = 10 ** 9 + 7 
s = len(R)
a = [[0] * 10 for _ in range(s + 1)]
a[0][0] = 1
for k in range(1, s + 1):
    for i in range(10):
        a[k][i] = sum(a[k - 1][j] for j in range(i + 1))
print((f(R) - f(str(int(L) - 1))) % p)
```

Вот тот же алгоритм, только на С++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
const long long p = pow(10, 9) + 7;
string decrease(string str)
{
    //Уменьшает число в строке на 1
    int l = str.length();
    if (str[l - 1] == '0')
    {
        int i = l - 1;
        while (str[i] == '0' && i > 0)
        {
            str = str.substr(0, i) + "9" + str.substr(i + 1, l);
            i--;
        }
        str = str.substr(0, i) + to_string(str[i] - '0' - 1) + str.substr(i + 1, l);
        return str;
    }
    else
        return str.substr(0, l - 1) + to_string(str[l - 1] - '0' - 1);
}
long long f(string n, vector<vector<long long>> a)
{
    long long res = 0; long long min_num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++)
    {
        int j = n[i] - '0';
        if (j < min_num)
            return res;
        else if (j > min_num)
        {
            vector<long long> tmp (0);
            for (int x = min_num; x < j; x++)
                tmp.push_back(a[n.length() - i][9 - x]);
            res = (res + accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0)) % p;
            min_num = j;
        }
    }
    return res + 1;
}
int main()
{
    string l; string r;
    cin >> l;
    cin >> r;
    long long s = r.length();
    vector<long long> tmp (10, 0);
    vector<vector<long long>> a (s + 1, tmp);
    a[0][0] = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= s; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            vector<long long> tmp (0);
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                tmp.push_back(a[k - 1][j]);
            a[k][i] = accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0) % p;
        }
    }
    cout << (f(r, a) - f(decrease(l), a)) % p;
}
```

Код на Python проходит все тесты, но код C++ падет (выдаёт неверный ответ) на первом же тесте за 0 секунд. Помогите пожалуйста, что не так в коде C++?
(Тестовые данные мне не известны)
Код С++ изменил. Переделал to_str(stoll(l) - 1) в функцию, которая делает то же самое, но отставляя l строкой. Всё равно не проходит....

Comment: А промежуточные значения входят в диапазон int? В питоне ведь целые числа произвольной длины.

Comment: Исправил на long long

Comment: Скорее всего, этого недостаточно. Надо все сложения проводить по указанному модулю

Comment: Это: res = (res + accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0)) % p, если я правильно понял?

Comment: видимо, да, и ещё в заполнении a[][]. Вы же можете проверить переполнение при отладке

Comment: Код С++ изменил. Переделал to_str(stoll(l) - 1) в функцию, которая делает то же самое, но отставляя l строкой. Всё равно не проходит....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если убрать в циклах промежуточные вектора, то дает одинаковые результаты с питоном.
Есть подозрение, что функция `accumulate()` отрабатывает некорректно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
const long long p = pow(10, 9) + 7;

long long f(string n, vector<vector<long long>> &a)
{
    long long res = 0; 
    int min_num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++)
    {
        int j = n[i] - '0';
        if (j < min_num)
            return res;
        else if (j > min_num)
        {
            for (int x = min_num; x < j; x++)
                res += a[n.length() - i][9 - x];
            min_num = j;
        }
    }
    return res + 1;
}

int main()
{
    string l = "91111111119111111111911111111191111111119111111111"; 
    string r = "9111111111911111111191111111119111111111911111111191111111119111111111";
    
    
    int s = r.length();
    cout << s << "\n";
    cout << decrease(l) << "\n";
    
    vector<long long> tmp (10, 0);
    vector<vector<long long>> a (s + 1, tmp);
    a[0][0] = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= s; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                a[k][i] += a[k - 1][j];
        }
    }
    
   
    long long rv = f(r, a);
    long long lv = f(decrease(l), a);
    
    cout << rv << "\n";
    cout << lv << "\n";
    cout << rv - lv << "\n";
    cout << (rv - lv) % p;
}
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Что-то не так было с std::accumulate. Без него всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм работает. Ответ у обеих программ (на С++ и Pyton) получается одинаковый.
Нашел только 1 ошибку:
3 раза получается остаток от деления `res % p` - в функции `f()` и 2 раза в `main()`. Причем в коде питона это делается 1 раз в конце. Не влияет на результат, пока числа в массиве меньше `p`, но при больших значениях может быть ошибка в вычислении, т.к. в массив заносится количество чисел, а в конце программы вычисляется разница между двумя количествами. И если делать разницу между остатками от деления, то может получиться даже отрицательное число.

```
long long f(string n, vector<vector<long long>> a)
{
  ...
            res = (res + accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0)) % p;
    return res + 1;
}
int main()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a[k][i] = accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0) % p;
        }
    cout << (f(r, a) - f(decrease(l), a)) % p;
}
```

Ну и небольшие замечания по ходу программы:
В циклах в `main()` и `f()` при подсчете не нужно создавать временный вектор, добавлять в него что-то а потом суммировать. Можно сразу суммировать.

```
long long f(string n, const vector<vector<long long>>& a)
{
        if (j >= min_num)
        {
/*            vector<long long> tmp (0);        // вместо этого 
            for (int x = min_num; x < j; x++)
                tmp.push_back(a[len - i][9 - x]);
            res = (res + accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0)) % p;
*/
            for (int x = min_num; x < j; x++)  // написать вот так
                res += a[len - i][8 - x];

            min_num = j;
        }
}
```

В функцию параметры лучше передавать по константным ссылкам

```
long long f(const string& n, const vector<vector<long long>> &a)
```

В функции `f()` значение `min_num` лучше сделать `int`, т.к. это индекс в массиве и его значения меняются от 0 до 9

```
long long f(string n, vector<vector<long long>> a)
{
    long long min_num = 0; // это индекс, он изменяется от 0 до 9
```

Интересные числа начинаются от чисел, состоящих как минимум из 1 цифры. Поэтому количество строк можно уменьшить. Нулевая строка - количество интересных чисел для одноцифровых чисел. Но с другой стороны - работает и ладно!

Comment: Соглашусь, но не совсем. При больших входных данных, например: L = 10^51 и R = 10^62 (а значения могут доходить да 10^100), данный код выдаёт -899198136, чего явно быть не должно

Answer (score 0):

C++. int: представляет целое число. В зависимости от архитектуры процессора может занимать 2 байта (16 бит) или 4 байта (32 бита). Диапазон предельных значений соответственно также может варьироваться от –32768 до 32767 (при 2 байтах) или от −2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 (при 4 байтах).

Может, в этом дело?

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я изменил где нужно int на long long, но всё равно не работает (в вопросе тоже изменил)